# how to hide and show input conditionally in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I Know this approach is not good in react js. but i don't know how to achieve same with react js. not getting the right way of doing this.
I have multiple input which I have to hide and show based on value selected from dropdown.

I am making this demo code for anyone who want to check.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hertz-k2ttl8?file=/src/App.js:0-1084

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const getInput = (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value;
    let data = document.getElementsByClassName(input);
    data.array.forEach((ele) => {
      if (ele.style.display === "none") {
        ele.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={getInput}>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="Both">Name && Address</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />

      <input
        className="Address Both"
        type="text"
        name="city"
        placeholder="City"
      />
      <input
        className="Address Both"
        type="text"
        name="pincode"
        placeholder="pincode"
      />

      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        className="Name Both"
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      <input
        className="Name Both"
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a state to store the selected value and then render the input based on that state:

```
const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

  const getInput = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={getInput}>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="Both">Name && Address</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />

      {selected === 'Address'&&<input
        className="Address Both"
        type="text"
        name="city"
        placeholder="City"
      />}
      // Similarly for the other inputs
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: hey thanks for the comment I have tried this method at first the problem is i have to some input based on selection where sometime all input based on selection that's why because this approach will make unnecessary mess in code and will lengthy if there will more option required in future

Comment: I want to make multiple input to show but rest should be display none that's the requirement in this suggested method it will only hide but space will remain there so what you suggest should another state for display handling or not ?

Comment: `display: none` won't save the space for the element, you want visibility hidden. You can do a similar thing, but instead of rendering, you can conditionally set the style depending on the state

Comment: could you update here what you saying it would much easier to understand point how i remove space or put display none https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hertz-k2ttl8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can take a state that keeps track of the selected dropDown items.

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({
city: false,
pincode: false,
...
})
```

Then based on the state show the input put conditionally in the JSX something like the following codes:

```
{
    selectedItem.city  && 
      <input
        className="Address Both"
        type="text"
        name="city"
        placeholder="City"
      />
}
```

You can follow the same thing for other input values also.

and don't forget to **update selectedItem** state on dropDown onChange function

Comment: hey thanks for the comment i tried this method but there is some problem with this code first it won't set display to none but hide second this i want to show all input sometime based on selection and sometime it will only specific input filed that's the main problem  I think i need to change the approach here and need to use object array and render input based on selection

Comment: @KuldeepSingh you can set city or address to true as a default useState value so that it'll prevent from displaying nothing.

Comment: my only problem to make display none could update here ? https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hertz-k2ttl8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think i should create another hook for control display none property so it will work along with this just as I want

Answer (score 0):

i have made changes in your codesandbox , you need to use conditional rendering to show or hide component.

Comment: hey thanks for the comment I am checking the code and let you know if this working

Comment: not able to see your changes send me the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-wildflower-9b60cy ,

Answer (score 0):

thank everyone who did answer to help me out
finally it working just as I want and I figure it out it was extra "br/" tag" which was the problem in the code

final code :

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [display, setdisplay] = useState({
    city: true,
    pincode: true,
    firstName: true,
    lastName: true
  });

  const getInput = (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value;
    switch (input) {
      case "Address": setdisplay({city: false, pincode: false, firstName: true, lastName: true }); break;
      case "Name": setdisplay({ city: true, pincode: true, firstName: false, lastName: false }); break;
      case "Both": setdisplay({city: false, pincode: false, firstName: false, lastName: false }); break;
      default: setdisplay({});
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={getInput}>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="Both">Both</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <input
        style={{ display: display.city ? "none" : "inline-block" }}
        className="Address Both"
        type="text"
        name="city"
        placeholder="City"
      />

      <input
        style={{ display: display.pincode ? "none" : "inline-block" }}
        className="Address Both"
        type="text"
        name="pincode"
        placeholder="pincode"
      />

      <input
        style={{ display: display.firstName ? "none" : "inline-block" }}
        className="Name Both"
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />

      <input
        style={{ display: display.lastName ? "none" : "inline-block" }}
        className="Name Both"
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```